# Webpack - Build two libraries

Tags: webpack

Im new to webpack 3. Im working on a project that we want to split in libraries: AppLibrary and MyLibrary.

My purpose is to be able to build these two files:

```
<script src="./MyLibrary.js"></script>
<script src="./AppLibrary.js"></script>
<script>

new AppLibrary(MyLibrary);

</script>
```

**I would like to do the building using only one webpack command instead of building the libraries with two commands**.

Because I dont know how to do it, **I have two webpack.config files. One for AppLibrary and another one for the MyLibrary.**

**appLibrary.webpack.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/App/app.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|device)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env']
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: 'AppLibrary'
  }
};
```

**library.webpack.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    library: './src/Library/Library.js'
  },
  externals: {
    "some": "some"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|externals)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env']
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: 'MyLibrary'
  }
};
```

Currently **I need to exec two commands to output two libraries.** Is there any way to handle this situation?

Folder structure is like follow:

```
- src
  |
  |- /dist
  |-- library.js
  |-- app.js
  |
  |- /Library
  |-- library.webpack.js
  |
  |- /App
  |-- app.webpack.js
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The options are the same for all exported libraries

To export multiple files using a singular config file, try setting an *entry* option in a single `webpack.config.js`.

The following example should be located in src and puts the two bundles in your dist folder.

```
entry: {
  app: "./App/app.js",
  library: "./Library/Library.js"
},
output: {
  filename: "[name].js",
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
}
```

---

### The options are the different for the exported libraries

To add multiple configurations to a webpack config file, you can use an array. When running webpack, all configurations are built. (Notice the square brackets after `module.exports =`)

**(Supported since webpack 3.1.0)**

```
module.exports = [
{
  entry: {
    app: "./App/app.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  }
  externals: ...
}, 
{
  entry: {
    library: "./Library/Library.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  }
  externals: ...
}]
```

Comment: one of the libraries defines externals. Can that be said in the webpack.config file? Not two of them but only one.

Comment: Sadly it is not possible to add different options to different entry points. To do this you would indeed need multiple configurations. I've edited my answer to suit your needs.

Comment: Well, going with single config isn't the way when you just want different `library` names :(

Comment: Actually you can manage both output names. 

The setting `filename: "[name].js"` in the `output` section means that the variable name will get replaced with the `entry` key for that file.

Change the `entry` keys, and you will have custom output names.

Comment: For the `library` option in the `output` section you can also use the same `[name]` placeholder. For more advanced options, see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/examples/multi-part-library/webpack.config.js

Answer (score 3):

Try to make two different npm scripts.

package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build-app": "webpack --config appLibrary.webpack.js",
    "build-lib": "webpack --config library.webpack.js",
    "build": "npm run build-app && npm run build-lib"
}
```